# Feasibility of having a large number of web services on a server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

At my company we currently have a large number (over 100) of production jobs that are run daily. The majority of them are downloading some data and storing it in a database. Some are run once day, some once a minute.

It is currently being managed by a monolithic c# application that has a built in scheduler that determines when to run each job, and each job is just a class inside the project. The problem is, that anytime someone wants to make a change to a job, or add a new one, they must recompile the project, turn off the service, redeploy the binaries, and then restart the service.

We are thinking of converting each job to be a standalone wcf service, then having the scheduler just call the service. That way, the scheduler app never needs to be updated, and making a change to a job would not effect the other jobs.

Does this sound feasible? Or are we just setting ourselves up for another set of problems? What sort of issues could we run into with have such a large # of services running on a machine?

Comment: Are the scheduler and services going to run on the same server?

Comment: It would probably start that way, although at some point we would most likely start moving services to a new server if performance becomes an issue

Comment: I assume the scheduler app reads some kind of config to know what jobs to run and how often?